# ffmpeg concat with video using image background

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, transcoding, image-stitching

Ffmpeg does not concat the media files correctly using various testing.  One of the videos is a .mp4 (h264 codec) video generated previously using a .mp3 and a jpeg background.  I've tried testing with various flags, closest I've gotten is below for the final output.

My main issue is the final video with the current test, the audio is about 3 seconds delayed once the two videos are stitched together.

Here are all the files I'm using:

Input Files:

- [audio.mp3](http://www.tcwebadmin.com/open_downloads/audio.mp3)
- [image.jpg](http://www.tcwebadmin.com/open_downloads/image.jpg)
- [main_video_raw.mp4](http://www.tcwebadmin.com/open_downloads/main_video_raw.mp4)

Output Files:

- [new_image_video_raw.mp4](http://www.tcwebadmin.com/open_downloads/new_image_video_raw.mp4)
- [new_image_video.mp4](http://www.tcwebadmin.com/open_downloads/new_image_video.mp4)
- [main_video.mp4](http://www.tcwebadmin.com/open_downloads/main_video.mp4)
- [final_output_video.mp4](http://www.tcwebadmin.com/open_downloads/final_output_video.mp4)

> **files.txt**
>
> file '/tmp/new_image_video.mp4'
>
> file '/tmp/main_video.mp4'

**Image Video Creation:**

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /tmp/image.jpg -i /tmp/audio.mp3 -acodec libfdk_aac -framerate 30 -vcodec libx264 -shortest /tmp/new_image_video_raw.mp4
```

**Part two:**

```
ffmpeg -threads 0 -i /tmp/new_image_video_raw.mp4 -vf "scale=w=560:h=320:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=560:320:(560-iw*min(560/iw\,320/ih))/2:(320-ih*min(560/iw\,320/ih))/2" -acodec libfdk_aac -af aresample=resampler=soxr -qp 20 -ar 44100 -r 30 -ab 128k -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -shortest -movflags +faststart /tmp/new_image_video.mp4 -y
```

**Main Video Transcode:**

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/main_video_raw.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*min(560/iw\,320/ih):ih*min(560/iw\,320/ih), pad=560:320:(560-iw*min(560/iw\,320/ih))/2:(320-ih*min(560/iw\,320/ih))/2" -acodec libfdk_aac -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 44100 -aspect 16:9 -qp 20  -framerate 30 -ab 128k -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -movflags +faststart /tmp/main_video.mp4 -y
```

**Concat Video:**

```
ffmpeg -threads 0 -f concat -safe 0 -i /tmp/files.txt -vf "scale=iw*min(560/iw\,320/ih):ih*min(560/iw\,320/ih), pad=560:320:(560-iw*min(560/iw\,320/ih))/2:(320-ih*min(560/iw\,320/ih))/2" -preset veryslow -crf 15 -acodec libfdk_aac -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 44100 -aspect 16:9 -qp 20  -framerate 30 -ab 128k -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -movflags +faststart /tmp/final_output_video.mp4 -y
```

**Output for new_image_video.mp4**

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] profile High, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] 264 - core 152 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:-3:-3 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=2.00:0.70 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-4 threads=10 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.20
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/new_image_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.76.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 560x320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 7:4], q=-1--1, 1 fps, 16384 tbn, 1 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.102.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 157 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41
frame=   73 fps=0.0 q=17.0 Lsize=     362kB time=00:00:16.00 bitrate= 185.3kbits/s speed=88.6x
video:49kB audio:308kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.166542%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] frame I:1     Avg QP: 4.09  size: 38729
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] frame P:18    Avg QP: 5.77  size:   843
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] frame B:54    Avg QP: 0.64  size:    49
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] consecutive B-frames:  1.4%  0.0%  0.0% 98.6%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] mb I  I16..4: 54.6% 18.9% 26.6%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  9.1%  0.1%  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:90.3%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:97.4%  L0:69.1% L1:30.9% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] 8x8 transform intra:18.9% inter:59.9%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 44.1% 45.3% 45.0% inter: 1.4% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 91%  2%  6%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 18% 18%  8%  5%  6%  7%  9%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 16%  8%  7% 10%  9% 10%  9%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 71% 12% 12%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] ref P L0: 79.3%  0.1% 19.5%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] ref B L0: 68.3% 30.5%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] ref B L1: 98.4%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x150ce00] kb/s:6.20
```

**Output for new_image_video.mp4 (Part 2)**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/new_image_video_raw.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:19.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 156 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 560x320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 7:4], 21 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 16384 tbn, 2 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 157 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] 264 - core 152 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=10 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=20 ip_ratio=1.40 pb_ratio=1.30 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/new_image_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.76.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 560x320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 7:4], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.102.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.102.100 libfdk_aac
[mp4 @ 0x2150cc0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file drop=0 speed=31.6x
frame=  569 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     351kB time=00:00:18.86 bitrate= 152.3kbits/s dup=579 drop=0 speed=32.5x
video:81kB audio:251kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5.851973%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] frame I:3     Avg QP:17.00  size: 23393
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] frame P:143   Avg QP:20.00  size:    26
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] frame B:423   Avg QP:21.67  size:    19
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] consecutive B-frames:  0.9%  0.0%  0.0% 99.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] mb I  I16..4: 54.7% 26.0% 19.4%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.7%  L0:23.7% L1:76.3% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] 8x8 transform intra:26.0% inter:14.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 39.8% 44.1% 43.4% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] i16 v,h,dc,p: 91%  3%  5%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 17% 15%  8%  6%  9%  6%  8%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 17%  6%  7% 10%  9% 11% 10%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] i8c dc,h,v,p: 71% 11% 13%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] ref P L0: 95.4%  0.7%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] ref B L0: 44.6% 55.4%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] ref B L1: 98.3%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2175560] kb/s:34.62
```

**Output for main_video.mp4**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/main_video_raw.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
  Duration: 00:01:02.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1347 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 959 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x758900] using SAR=64/63
[libx264 @ 0x758900] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x758900] profile High, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 0x758900] 264 - core 152 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=10 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=20 ip_ratio=1.40 pb_ratio=1.30 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/main_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.76.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 560x320 [SAR 64:63 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.102.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.102.100 libfdk_aac
[mp4 @ 0x755900] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file11.1x
frame= 1557 fps=275 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5144kB time=00:01:02.32 bitrate= 676.1kbits/s speed=  11x
video:4119kB audio:975kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.989500%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] frame I:13    Avg QP:17.00  size: 34937
[libx264 @ 0x758900] frame P:657   Avg QP:20.00  size:  3546
[libx264 @ 0x758900] frame B:887   Avg QP:21.69  size:  1615
[libx264 @ 0x758900] consecutive B-frames: 18.9% 12.6%  8.1% 60.4%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] mb I  I16..4: 12.5% 51.8% 35.7%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  1.9%  1.0%  P16..4: 17.9%  9.3%  8.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:61.3%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.3%  0.3%  B16..8: 18.0%  5.6%  2.4%  direct: 2.8%  skip:70.6%  L0:33.9% L1:42.5% BI:23.6%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] 8x8 transform intra:55.4% inter:56.4%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 84.0% 93.3% 75.0% inter: 12.6% 14.9% 3.3%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] i16 v,h,dc,p:  8% 38%  3% 51%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 20%  8%  7%  9%  9% 10% 10% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 20%  9%  8% 11% 10% 10%  9%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] i8c dc,h,v,p: 41% 26% 17% 16%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.2% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] ref P L0: 72.3% 14.4%  9.7%  3.6%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] ref B L0: 89.9%  7.7%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] ref B L1: 97.1%  2.9%
[libx264 @ 0x758900] kb/s:541.66
```

**Outupt for concat:**

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib -ldl' --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libass --enable-libvidstab --enable-libsoxr --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libwebp --enable-fontconfig --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 73.100 / 55. 73.100
  libavcodec     57.102.100 / 57.102.100
  libavformat    57. 76.100 / 57. 76.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 98.100 /  6. 98.100
  libswscale      4.  7.102 /  4.  7.102
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/main_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
  Duration: 00:01:02.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1347 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 959 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] using SAR=64/63
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] profile High, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] 264 - core 152 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=10 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=20 ip_ratio=1.40 pb_ratio=1.30 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/new_image_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.76.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 560x320 [SAR 64:63 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.102.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.102.100 libfdk_aac
[mp4 @ 0x1560900] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file1.2x
frame= 1557 fps=277 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5144kB time=00:01:02.32 bitrate= 676.1kbits/s speed=11.1x
video:4119kB audio:975kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.989500%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] frame I:13    Avg QP:17.00  size: 34937
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] frame P:657   Avg QP:20.00  size:  3546
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] frame B:887   Avg QP:21.69  size:  1615
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] consecutive B-frames: 18.9% 12.6%  8.1% 60.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] mb I  I16..4: 12.5% 51.8% 35.7%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  1.9%  1.0%  P16..4: 17.9%  9.3%  8.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:61.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.3%  0.3%  B16..8: 18.0%  5.6%  2.4%  direct: 2.8%  skip:70.6%  L0:33.9% L1:42.5% BI:23.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] 8x8 transform intra:55.4% inter:56.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 84.0% 93.3% 75.0% inter: 12.6% 14.9% 3.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] i16 v,h,dc,p:  8% 38%  3% 51%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 20%  8%  7%  9%  9% 10% 10% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 20%  9%  8% 11% 10% 10%  9%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] i8c dc,h,v,p: 41% 26% 17% 16%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.2% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] ref P L0: 72.3% 14.4%  9.7%  3.6%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] ref B L0: 89.9%  7.7%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] ref B L1: 97.1%  2.9%
[libx264 @ 0x1563900] kb/s:541.66
```

Comment: `mpdecimate` will remove duplicate frames. For a video created from a single image, that's **all frames** after the first! Why is that filter there?

Comment: I was just testing it, when I use mpdecimate the second video is the correct length, but when I don't use that filter then the first video is much longer and ends up being about 10 times as long as the created video with the jpeg background.

Comment: Show the properties of both files: `ffmpeg -i file`

Comment: I added it to my op above

Comment: Please provide input files and output file from your test.

Comment: I added the files used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the main_video.mp4 audio track was variable.  I was able to get it working by transcoding the video like:

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/main_video_raw.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*min(560/iw\,320/ih):ih*min(560/iw\,320/ih), pad=560:320:(560-iw*min(560/iw\,320/ih))/2:(320-ih*min(560/iw\,320/ih))/2" -acodec libfdk_aac -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 44100 -aspect 16:9 -qp 20 -framerate 30 -ab 128k -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" -b:v 2500K -minrate 2500K -maxrate 2500K -bufsize 2M -shortest -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -movflags +faststart /tmp/main_video.mp4 -y
```